# Primefaces LightBox slows down loading of the page opened inside LightBox

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces LightBox popup window in my application. The problem I am facing is when I click the link to open the corresponding page, it's too slow to display the page through LightBox. It's take more time to loading. How can I solve it?

Link for LightBox :

```
<p:lightBox style="display:inline">
    <a href="login.xhtml">Login&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
</p:lightBox>
```

When I click the link, the corresponding page `login.xhtml` is to be opened through LightBox. I am using PrimeFaces 3.0 and JSF 2.0.

Comment: if any of the answers to questions you post to Stack Overflow are acceptable, please mark them as such by clicking the check beside the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Dialog component as a replacement for LightBox for your scenario. Dialog can replicate Lightbox's popup capabilities with the additional ability to make the login page modal (e.g. you can force the user to either complete the login process or close the login popup). Furthermore, unlike LightBox, Dialog is capable of pre-rendering its content so when the Dialog is popped-up, the user wont experience any UI delay due to the popup going to fetch its content. Note, if you want to keep the login page in a separate xhtml file, you can include it inside the Dialog component using a Facelets include.